# Interactive heatmap slice as separate plot for browser

Tags: plotting

I want to create an interactive online version of a static plot I generated with gnuplot5. I have limited experience with generating dynamic plots for webpages and need a rough direction where to go to waste the least amount of time researching and trying different frameworks.

desired plot: 2d heatmap with of a file with 3d data. mouse position over plot is selector for 2d slice of heatmap which is displayed next to the heatmap. (bonus realtime capabilities)

Is D3 a viable candidate?

Thank you in advance